# Add Class dynamically to checkbox field in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, asp.net-core

I am a beginner in Angular I simply want to achieve that I have a checkbox and i want to set a class on it according to its value i.e if checked set the css class active and if unchecked set class inactive
HTML

```
 <div class="field">
                    <div class="center">
                        <mat-checkbox formControlName="isDeployed">Is Deployed</mat-checkbox>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

TS

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditComponent>, 
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data, 
private _snackBar: MatSnackBar, public dialog: MatDialog,) { 

  this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required],
  isDeployed: [{value: false, disabled: true}, null],
});
}
```

I got the checkbox value from data.isDeployed what I need to do if its true set class on html element accordingly.

```
    .active{
    color:purple;
           }
    .inactive{
     color:grey;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) binding with the ternary operator

Try the following

```html
<mat-checkbox [ngClass]="editForm.value.isDeployed ? 'active' : 'inactive'" formControlName="isDeployed">
  Is Deployed
</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<section [ngClass]="value ? 'active' : 'inactive'"></section>
```

if value is true .active class set and if value false .inactive class set